# I need help to have an email form on my website

Tags: html, email

[My code is pasted below] I want to set something in my page so people can send me emails without having to open theirs, but when I try it gives me the "file not found" error.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" 
enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: *"so people can send me emails without having to open theirs"* – You will need some server-side code which will send the actual email. `mailto:` links are to open the user's email program. It won't magically send email without that.

Comment: html is a static markup language it cannot deal with dynamic data. To send email you have to use server side language like php, .Net etc

Comment: It opens a dialog on my android 7, do you have a default email client setup on your system?

Comment: @PatrickSturm, you're right, this should actually bring up an email composition with some stuff prefilled. I thought you could only do that with `mailto:` in `<a>` tags. It sounds like the poster wants to have an email programmatically sent though, which this will of course not do.

Answer (score 0):

Your form `action` is set to an email `mailto:` type address, which operates similarly to having a `mailto:` link, but won't actually send the email itself. I'll try to explain:

**Email Links**

You can use links with `mailto:email@email.com` as the address, and all this does is prompts an email composition screen in whatever email service they have selected as default. If you have Outlook and click that link, it will open up a new email window with email@email.com filled out in the 'To:' field.

Example: `<a href='mailto:email@email.com'>Click here to email me!</a>`

However, there *is* actually a way to get forms to behave in a similar manner, but you still must have an email client installed that can be used -- no emails will be sent just because a user completes the form on your website. [Here's an example of that in action](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail), and it looks like that's what you're doing right now.

**Email Forms**

Using HTML forms, you can take input from your users directly on the webpage using input boxes like you have in your example here. However, if you want that form to actually send an email, you will need is a form handler -- a script that can actually take these inputs and do something with them. In your case, you're trying to send an email, and a static HTML website cannot do that. You need to use something like PHP to actually send an email.

Example: `<form action='handler.php' method='GET'> .. your form inputs </form>`

The 'file not found' error you're getting is because it's looking at your action attribute, and trying to access something called `mailto:someone@example.com` which doesn't exist.

You're on the right track, but let me suggest some resources that might help you:

- [mailto | HTML mailto link](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.html) - A better explanation of the `mailto:` URL scheme.
- [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) - To give you another example, here's the similar `tel:` link in action.
- [enter link description here](https://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php) - A general HTML and PHP email form that will serve as a good example.